# Xcode - how to build a Mac project without generating .app file

Tags: xcode, macos, executable

I need to get simple executable file (resource folder must be in the same dir) without pack it in .app. How can i do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Xcode to create an OS X command line tool project: File, New, Project..., OS X, Command Line Tool. See http://www.bricewilson.net/blog/2013/01/11/command-line-tool-resources/ for details.

After building your project, find the executable from the Xcode Organizer: Window, Organizer, Projects, *your-project*, Derived Data.